# vstest console output verbosity switch ignore by MSBuild

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, msbuild-task

We are trying to reduce the console verbosity of our test runs in our Azure DevOps pipelines.
Due to the number of tests and complexity, we wrapped the VSTest.Console.exe run in MSBuild targets.

We configured our vstest.console.exe runs with the /logger:console;verbosity=minimal. When running the vstest command manually through command prompt this works fine, it only outputs the skipped tests and the end result summary, as intended.

When executed through MSBuild targets, even with the simplest target we confirmed, the output to the console is the full VSTest console output as if its in normal verbosity.
We are also setting the MSBuild verbosity to minimal, but this has no effect on the VSTest output.

Here is the target which we can reproduce it with

```
  <Target Name="RunTestWorker" Outputs="$(VSTestConsoleExitCode)">
    <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\..\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe&quot; &quot;ProjectA.SpecflowTest.dll&quot; /Platform:x64 /logger:console;verbosity=q /logger:trx;LogFileName=TestTrxFile.trx"
        ContinueOnError="True"
        WorkingDirectory="$(TestResultsDirectory)..">
    </Exec>
  </Target>
```

Executed with this MSBuild call:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" "TestBuild.targets" /verbosity:m /t:RunTestWorker
```

We tried additional [MSBuild Exec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2022) options like ConsoleToMSBuild and EchoOff, but this didn't really change much.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Have you tried `/logger:console;verbosity=quiet`? I don't think that `q` is recognized as a valid value for `verbosity`.

Comment: we tried with /logger:console;verbosity=minimal which should be a recognized value

Answer (score 0):

This [example from Microsoft's docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/main/docs/report.md#example) wraps the arguments after `/logger:` in quotes:

```
vstest.console.exe Tests.dll /logger:"console;verbosity=minimal"
```

I tried this from the command line without the trx logger and it did reduce logging compared to normal.

So in your case:

```
/logger:&quot;console;verbosity=quiet&quot; /logger:&quot;trx;LogFileName=TestTrxFile.trx&quot;
```